# How to create a conda environment shortcut on Windows

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, anaconda

With Anaconda installed I got a `anaconda base` shortcut on Windows startmanu. To open the virtualenv I created (e.g., `myenv`), I have to click the `anaconda base` and type in `activate myenv` in the opened cmd window.

How can I create a shortcut to get to `myenv` with one-click, without open-and-typing like the above?

I've tried to create a copy of the base shortcut and change its command property i.e., `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Programs\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\myenv`. It does open the myenv cmdline, but seemed lost some buildin command,like `conda`.

I guess I need a little bit help on Windows bat skills.

Comment: I think you may have your quoting wrong, `%WinDir%\System32\cmd.exe /K "C:\Programs\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\myenv"`. Type `cmd /?` at the prompt for the usage help on that particular command.

Comment: @Compo, using your version I got the same results, i.e., myenv opened,but some commands(e.g., `conda`) are not in the environment. ;-(

Comment: I only provided a fix to your incorrect quoting, not an answer to your question, _which would have been provided in the answer area, not the comment area_. It was only so because you have not provided sufficient information in your question area for me to confidently provide an answer.

Comment: Well the answer would be in the batch file itself.

Comment: Since I also use `git-bash`, I found I can put `source /c/.../activate /c/.../myenv` into my `.bashrc` file. After that when I launch `git-bash`, it goes into myenv and works fine!  I'll go with  `git-bash` now.

Comment: It's funny that you can create a shortcut to the base environment with `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\appl\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat base` and that will have conda.exe in the path and if you `conda activate myenv` from there conda.exe will remain in the PATH. But if you try to directly activate the `myenv` it won't have access to conda.exe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

putting the comments above together in a simple batch script works flawlessly:

```
@echo off    
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat <env-name>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Adding a `cd /d e:\my-working-dir` before the last line make it totally perfect. Thanks man.

Comment: This isn't a "shortcut"

Comment: Create a shortcut to cmd, set Target to %windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" %USERPROFILE%\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat base (I use Miniconda3).  Double click to open a cmd prompt w/the env already activated.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me.  The only change is that the parameter to `activate.bat` is simply the env name (not the full path) as you would normally type it after an activate command.  Your quotes were fine, BTW.  For instance:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat myenv
```

Comment: This activates the environment, yes, but the conda.exe will not not be there (unless you already added C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts to you global PATH which is not the recommended option when installing Anaconda

Comment: `conda.bat` which is called by `activate.bat` already takes care of the PATH.

Answer (score 2):

For miniconda it's:

```
@echo off    
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Scripts
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat video
```

Was gonna leave it as a comment on Jonathan's, but I'm new ><.

Answer (score 1):

Mine automatically created a shortcut for Spyder with this format:

```
C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Anaconda3\envs\py36 C:\Anaconda3\envs\py36\pythonw.exe C:\Anaconda3\envs\py36\Scripts\spyder-script.py
```

Comment: This is a great option for non command line apps. I just used is as `C:\Miniconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Miniconda3\cwp.py C:\Miniconda3\envs\env0 app.exe` . Replace env0 and app.exe with your respective values and no cmd.exe will be shown

Comment: this requires short paths, as the full string must fit within 259 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Before creating new environment you can specify:

```
conda config --set shortcuts true
```

After that, you can see shortcuts for your new environment.

Answer (score 0):

I use `ConEmu` terminal, with traditional `cmd.exe` shell. Here's what my shortcut to `MiniConda3` looks like:
`C:\Users\nmz787\Downloads\conemu_22_08_07\ConEmu64.exe -run  {Shells::cmd} & C:\Users\nmz787\Miniconda3\condabin\conda.bat activate`

Answer (score -2):

You can get around this by installing  the `conda` package into the environment that you want to activate.

From an Anaconda Prompt (from where conda is already accessible):

```
conda install -n myenv conda
```

Then you can create a windows shortcut with target `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\appl\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat myenv`

This is suboptimal as it pollutes your environment with the `conda` dependencies, and I wouldn't recommend it.

The other alternative is to add the `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts` directory to the `PATH` environment variable.